# console.log not showing expected object properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the following code in javascript in my node.js application.
However certain objects are not stored in my variable `appointment`. Even if I set them, when I directly access them it works: `console.log(appointment.test);`

What have I done wrong in this code?

```
var appointment = {
    subscribed: false,
    enoughAssis: false,
    studentSlotsOpen: false
};
console.log(appointment);
for (var key in appointmentsDB[i]) {
    appointment[key] = appointmentsDB[i][key];    
}

appointment.test= "res";

console.log(appointment.test);
console.log(appointment);
```

And here is the produced output:

```
{ subscribed: false,
  enoughAssis: false,
  studentSlotsOpen: false }
res
{ comment: 'fsadsf',
  room: 'dqfa',
  reqAssi: 3,
  maxStud: 20,
  timeSlot: 8,
  week: 31,
  year: 2013,
  day: 3,
  _id: 51f957e1200cb0803f000001,
  students: [],
  assis: [] }
```

The variable `console.log(appointmentsDB[i])` looks as:

```
{ comment: 'fsadsf',
  room: 'dqfa',
  reqAssi: 3,
  maxStud: 20,
  timeSlot: 8,
  week: 31,
  year: 2013,
  day: 3,
  _id: 51f957e1200cb0803f000001,
  students: [],
  assis: [] }
```

The following command:

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(appointmentsDB[i]), Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(appointmentsDB[i])));
```

Shows:

```
[ '_activePaths',
  '_events',
  'errors',
  '_maxListeners',
  '_selected',
  '_saveError',
  '_posts',
  'save',
  '_pres',
  '_validationError',
  '_strictMode',
  'isNew',
  '_doc',
  '_shardval' ] [ 'assis',
  'timeSlot',
  'db',
  '_schema',
  'id',
  'base',
  'day',
  'collection',
  'reqAssi',
  'constructor',
  'comment',
  'year',
  'room',
  'students',
  'week',
  '_id',
  'maxStud' ]
```

However I would expect that my last output also provides the entries test, subscribed, enoughAssis and studentSlotsOpen. What is wrong in this code?

The solution I found was to manually copy the elements I wanted to.

Comment: What is `appointmentsDB[i]`?

Comment: it is an object retrieved from the Database.

Comment: Did you copy a custom `toString` or `toJSON` method maybe?

Comment: No all the code I use is above.

Comment: No it's not, you didn't show us what exactly that `appointmentsDB[i]` object is. What database are you using, can you construct that object without a DB?

Comment: I use a mongo db. I printed the object using console.log(appointmentsDB[i]).

Comment: When I run your code in node.js, it works fine (outputs all the expected properties for the last console log). Something somewhere else is messing with `appointment`. (I assigned 0 to `i` and your indicated object to `appointmentsDB[0]`.)

Comment: Please do a `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(appointmentsDB[i]), Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(appointmentsDB[i])))` and post the results. It's not a plain object!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have a [Document object](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document-js) instead of a plain object. Those have a custom [`toJSON` method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toJSON) which only yields the properties of your schema and the `_id`, but nothing else. If you are copying that method with your for-in-loop onto the `appointment` object, it will get serialized differently as well when logged.

Try

```
for (var key in appointmentsDB[i].toObject()) {
    appointment[key] = appointmentsDB[i][key];    
}

appointment.test= "res";

console.log(appointment);
```